# Terragrunt Cascading Groups

Tags: terragrunt

I have a hub and [spoke network topology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/hub-spoke-network-topology) that I'm using Terragrunt to manage. I have a single networking hub module, ipam module, and transit gateway module. These are dependencies of my spokes.

I have 100 spokes.

I'm using the [aws-ia/terraform-aws-vpc](https://github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-vpc) module for my spoke VPC's. I just learned that the secondary CIDR requires either a targeted or separate apply. I also need to share the eventual subnets with other accounts. Can Terragrunt do cascading groups like so:

```
root
 ├─hub
 ├─ipam
 ├─tgw
 ├─spokes
 │  ├─spoke1
 │  │  ├─vpc
 │  │  ├─secondary_cidr
 │  │  ├─sharing  
 │  └─spoke2
 │     ├─vpc
 │     ├─secondary_cidr
 │     ├─sharing
```

If this is possible, please provide a complete example including code. If not, what are my alternatives?